# Jquery effect's delayed on Fixed Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Firstly hi. I start frontend for onemonths so I am beginner. I want to make fixed menu when the scroll is going down. I do it. But if I going up, effects being delayed 3s & 4s. I can't see the problem. Thanks for helping :).

```
Html code: 

<div id="header">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="anasayfa.html"><img src="resimler/3.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div id="menu1">
      <ul>
        <li class="onecıkar"> <a href="kisiselilan.html"> Kisisel İlan Ver </a> </li>
        <li class="onecıkar"> <a href="firmakaydet.html"> Firma Kaydet </a> </li>
        <li class="ozel"> <a href="kurumsalilanver.html"> Kurumsal İlan Ver </a> </li>
        <li class="ozel" id="menu2"> <a href="iletisim.html"> İletisim </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="menubar"><img src="resimler/menu46.png" /> </div>

  <div id="kayıt">
    <form class="kadi">
      <p class="yazı"> Kullanıcı Adı <span> : </span> </p>
      <input type="text" name="Kullanici_Id" class="kkadi" />
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="yazı" id="sifre"> Sifre <span>: </span> </p>
      <input type="password" class="kkadi" name="Password" />

      <br>

      <p id="pass"><a href="#"> Sifremi Unuttum </a></p>
      <br>

      <input class="altbtn" id="giris" type="submit" value="Giriş" />
      <input class="altbtn" id="kayıtol" type="submit" value="Kayıt Ol" />

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS and Jquery are here:

https://jsfiddle.net/carnvall/7yfg784c/2/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the whole menu fixed using css:
try this:

```
`div#navbar {
  margin-left: 100px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

`